# Nest thermostat. No fan with heating

Tags: electrical, thermostat, nest

Here is how my Nest behaves with 3 different scenarios. My question is how can I get my fan to turn on automatically with my heat. Is it possible i have it wired incorrectly? Attached is my wiring diagram.

When my Nest is set to cool: The fan and the AC both turn on. There is no fan symbol indicating the fan is running on my Nest.

When Nest is set to heat: the furnace comes on. Fan does not. I can manually turn on the fan and it will start running.

I am able to run fan only without heating or cooling.

[image: wiring]

Comment: Wild guess here, it sounds like the A/C may be controlling the fan through its logic board and neither the Nest nor the Furnace is controlling the fan.  Did you just replace one or more old thermostats with the Nest?  Did you make note of how they were connected?  Diagnosing this requires carefully tracing all the control wires.  I'd start from the fan and work backwards.

Comment: What make and model is your air-handler/furnace?

Comment: How do you "manually" turn on the fan?